# Enabling WSO2 IDP Audit logs

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

I would like to enable the WSO2 Carbon 5.5 audit logs. I have followed these documents to get the audit.log enabled, but nothing appears to change.

https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS570/Working+with+Product+Observability

https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS550/Using+the+User+Management+Errors+Event+Listener

I am however not seeing any special errors in the wso2carbon.log, although my audit.log is completely empty.

I also tried requesting for Groups & Users https://localhost:9443/wso2/scim/Users 
in the hope of something would get audited, but still no luck.

Comment: Try adding a new user (Through SCIM or management console) and check the audit logs.

Comment: Yes, I did that. But the audit logs don't change. I tried adding, deleting. Even accessing through the https://localhost:9443/wso2/scim/Groups

Answer (score 1):

**https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS570/Working+with+Product+Observability**

The following note in the above doc.

> In order to use this feature, apply the WUM update for WSO2 IS 5.5.0
>   released on 2018-11-28.

This feature is available as a WUM update only (for subscription users). Open source users have to switch to the latest version WSO2 IS 5.8.0 to use this.

**https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS550/Using+the+User+Management+Errors+Event+Listener**

This doc also says the following.

> The UserManagementAuditLogger is responsible for adding audit logs
>   during the execution of successful user management scenarios, and the
>   UserMgtFailureAuditLogger handles the audit logs during the failure
>   scenarios. Follow the instructions below to enable the improved audit
>   logger introduced with the WUM update.

This available for open source usage from the 5.6.0 version.